# Palindrome Linked List

Tags: java, reverse, singly-linked-list, palindrome

Given a singly linked list, I want to determine if it is a palindrome. For my method, I chose to reverse the first half of the linked list and then compare if the two halves of the linked list have equivalent elements. Previously, I placed the line fast = fast.next.next at the end of the first while loop(below the 4 other lines). However, when I did that, I received a Null Pointer Exception. Now, when I shift it to the first line in the while loop, I get no errors and my program is accepted. Can someone explain to me why this is so? Thank you! Below is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {

        if(head == null || head.next == null){
            return true;
        }
        ListNode fast = head;
        ListNode slow = head;
        ListNode prev = null;

        while(fast != null && fast.next != null){
            fast = fast.next.next;
            ListNode temp = slow.next;
            slow.next = prev;
            prev = slow;
            slow = temp;

        }

        if(fast != null){
            slow = slow.next;
        }

        while(prev != null && prev.val == slow.val){
            prev = prev.next;
            slow = slow.next;
        }

        return slow == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Previously, I placed the line fast = fast.next.next at the end of the first while loop(below the 4 other lines). However, when I did that, I received a Null Pointer Exception. Now, when I shift it to the first line in the while loop, I get no errors and my program is accepted.*" - Since you did not change `fast` within the body of the loop, the placement of the statement `fast = fast.next.next;` within the loop does not change the program's semantics. You should include the exception message, as well as the original code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if you call `slow.next = prev` first, you lose reference of what would be `first.next.next`. Why is this?

Per your initializations:

```
fast -> head
slow -> head
prev -> null
```

Now in your while loop, you are checking if `fast.next` is not pointing to `null`.
Therefore, `fast.next.next` is valid.
However, do note that `slow.next` is pointing to the the same reference as `fast.next`. For the sake of the explanation we will say that there are both pointing to a memory address called SOMETHING.

```
fast (HEAD) -> next -> SOMETHING
slow (HEAD) -> next -> SOMETHING
```

IF you put `fast.next.next` at the top of the while-loop, itis valid, because it is still pointing to something.

IF you put fast.next.next at the bottom of the while-loop, then the line
`slow.next = prev` will first set `head.next` as `null`.

You now modified `head.next` to point to nothing.
Because fast was pointing to the head as well, `fast.next` now points to null as well.

```
fast (head) -> next -> NULL
```

So calling fast.next.next will throw a null reference exception.

Hope this helps.